# jquery modify next elements text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reduce 5 days from the value of field Time Countdown 2015-10-15
final value should be 2015-10-10

```
<tr>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;" width="30%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable">Time Countdown&nbsp;</td>
<td width="70%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable ">2015-10-15</td>
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it in JQuery
This is what I have bean trying:

```
var date =    $('td').filter(function(i) {
           $(this).html().indexOf('*Time Countdown*') >= 0;
}).next().text();

var newDate = new Date(date) - 5;
//post the value to the same field.

 var date =    $('td').filter(function(i) {
               $(this).html().indexOf('*Time Countdown*') >= 0;
    }).next().text(newDate);
```

Comment: if it works it looks elegant enough for me.

Comment: you're missing a `return` inside your filter functions.

Comment: In addition to what @Jamiec said, It also looks like you're returning a jQuery object when you call `.next()` as the last chained function. I don't think that can be converted to a date. I think you'll need to call `.next().text()` to get the `2015-10-15` date value back prior to creating a `new Date(...);`

Comment: _"trying to reduce 5 days from the value"_ , _"final value should be 2015-10-15"_ Should "final value" be "2015-10-10" ?

Comment: yes thank you, fixed it.

Comment: Be careful with dates - dates are hard! Use a library which deals with parsing/formatting dates correctly. My answer attempts to use native JS, but its a horrible way of dealing with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to reduce 5 days from the value of field Time Countdown

If interpret Question correctly , try using `:contains()` , `.text()` , `Date.prototype.getDate()` , `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
$("table td:contains(Time Countdown)")
.next("td").text(function(_, date) {
  var d = new Date(date); 
  return date.replace(/\d+$/, d.getDate() - 5)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="white-space: nowrap;" width="30%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable">Time Countdown&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="70%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable ">2015-10-15</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one chain, by finding the right `td`, and supplying a function to the `.text()` function which returns the replaced data. You can also get access to the current text inside that method too.

```js
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().indexOf("Time Countdown")>-1;  
}).next().text(function(){
    var current = $(this).text().split('-');
    var d = new Date(current[0],current[1],current[2]);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;" width="30%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable">Time Countdown&nbsp;</td>
<td width="70%" class="clsGridCellBase searchable ">2015-10-15</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of flaws:

- The filter won't find the cells with the date given
- The calculation is too simple

I've made a fiddle here which is working: http://jsfiddle.net/daeLu5ee/

main part:

```
var date =    $('#in').html();
var newDate = new Date(date);
newDate.setTime(newDate.getTime() - (5*24*3600*1000));

 $('#out').html(newDate.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: you added ID's to the html, I cannot change the html at this point.